# Adding data to a dataframe, from multiple other dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Edit:
I think i've solved it, leaving it here incase anyone finds it helpful (or can improve what I have done)
My solution was:

```html
totalYield2017.loc['Q1'] = [fishLandingsQ1_df['Landed Weight (tonnes)'].sum(), fishLandingsQ1_df['Value(£)'].sum()]
```

I have created a blank dataframe

[image: image 1]

I want to populate it with sums of columns from other dataframes.

I have 4 other dataframes (one for each quarter, Q1, Q2 etc) that have columns for weight and value. I want to create a sum of each of those columns for the first row in my blank dataframe.

I have included a picture of one of the quarters dataframes, its the last 2 columns I want the sums of to be inputted into the blank dataframe

[image: Image 2]

Comment: You can post the solution as answer rather than at the top of question.

Comment: Ah, i'll do that, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think i've solved it, leaving it here in case anyone finds it helpful (or can improve what I have done)
My solution was;

*totalYield2017.loc['Q1'] = [fishLandingsQ1_df['Landed Weight (tonnes)'].sum(), fishLandingsQ1_df['Value(£)'].sum()]*